# Help with using the Search Module without a form

Tags: module, search

Is it possible in Expression Engine, using the latest version, to run a search query, without having to use a form? Meaning, I'd like to create an api endpoint like so:

```
http://localhost/v1/search/large+pants
```

So the view file would grab segment_3, and use that to search the various channels I have?

If that's not possible, then I ask, is it possible to do a post like how the regular search module works, but not require any of the extra params in the request, just send over the "keywords"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that is not possible with the first party search module. It would be possible to build queries like that with [Low Search](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-search) or [Solspace SuperSearch](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/super-search) however.